# onpaste event on asp.net textbox in internet explorer not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, copy-paste

this is my textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxFlagDes" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" MaxLength="30" Width="150px" onkeypress="return this.value.length<=30"></asp:TextBox>
```

here's the script:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtBoxFlagDes").on("input", function () {
            LimtCharacters(this, 30);
        });
    });
    function LimtCharacters(txtMsg, CharLength) {
        chars = txtMsg.value.length;
        if (chars > CharLength) {
            txtMsg.value = txtMsg.value.substring(0, CharLength);                
        }
    }
</script>
```

when the user copies some text and paste into textbox then it takes whole text from the clipboard in short the script is not working. not getting the problem

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Browser's compatibility of input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) it will not support **IE<9**

```
Feature             Chrome     Firefox     Internet Explorer    ....
Basic support       (Yes)      2           9
```

Comment: yeah but i m using IE 11 and it is not working in any of the browser

Answer (score 0):

Your script is checking the input by user or keypress event. but when copied text pasting into the Test box this event is not going to fire. So obviously your scipt will not work in that case.

Might be after past the text in the text box you can validate that text on lost focus.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you provide any other solution

Comment: it is not working on my website showing following error: Unhandled exception at line 33, column 9 in http://localhost:59771/Surviellance/GSMFlagMaster.aspx

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'onpaste' of undefined or null reference

Comment: In this case your javascript is not identifying the server side control id. Might you can use control's  client id in the script. In that way once control will get identified this errors should be resolved. Hope this helps.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var test = document.getElementById("<%= txtBoxFlagDes.ClientID %>");
        test.onPaste = function (e) {
            var max = test.getAttribute("maxlength");
            e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain').slice(0, max);
        };
    </script>` this is the code i m using but then too test is getting null reference